# In Xcode 11, how do you quick-open a file in a new tab or new window?

Tags: xcode, xcode11

Prior to Xcode 11, you could use `cmd+shift+o` to open the quick open menu, and then use `opt+shift+enter` to show the little jump dialog to decide where to open the file, e.g.

[image]

Note that the dialog has spots for opening in new window or new tab.

In XCode 11, with all the editor improvements (which are awesome), the little jump dialog has been replaced with some blue highlights that show up in the current window. This seems nice, but I can't figure out how to get a file to open in a new tab or new window.

[image]

Didn't realize how important this was in my workflow until it went away :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

When the highlighting appears

- press <kbd>→</kbd> then <kbd>↩</kbd> to open the file in a new editor on the right.
- press <kbd>↓</kbd> then <kbd>↩</kbd> to open the file in a new editor on the bottom.
- press <kbd>⌘T</kbd> to open the file in a new tab.
- press <kbd>⇧⌘T</kbd> to open the file in a new window.

If multiple editors are open you can navigate with the arrow keys to specify the insertion location for the new editor.